# css движение слайдера

Tags: jquery, css

```css
.content-wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
   }
.rowwrap {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}
.rowwrap .viewslide {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 270px;
  background: lime;
}
@media (min-width: 670px) {
  .rowwrap .viewslide {
    width: 536px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .rowwrap .viewslide {
    width: 804px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .rowwrap .viewslide {
    width: 1070px;
  }
}
.rowwrap .left {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: green;
}
.rowwrap .left img {
  width: 49px;
  height: 49px;
}
.rowwrap .right {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: green;
}
.rowwrap .right img {
  width: 49px;
  height: 49px;
}
.rowwrap .slideritems {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}
.rowwrap .slideritems .item {
  width: 248px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
    <section class="content-wrap">
        <div class="rowwrap">
            <div class="left"><img src="img/leftarrow.png"></div>
            <div class="viewslide">                
                <div class="slideritems">
                    <div class="item">item</div>
                    <div class="item">item</div>
                    <div class="item">item</div>
                    <div class="item">item</div>
                    <div class="item">item</div>
                    <div class="item">item</div>
                    <div class="item">item</div>
                    <div class="item">item</div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="right"><img src="img/rightarrow.png"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Хотел сделать слайдер через overflow: hidden. и вроде бы мысль простая, сделать при нажатии на стрелку влева движение целого блока на определенное количество пикселей влево или вправо соответственно. Но как решить проблему с тем, чтобы нельзя было бесконечно щелкать так? может есть какой то другой способ сделать слайдер максимально простым? подскажите пожалуйста. готовые варианты мне не интересны, цель именно научиться самому.

Comment: Раз уж цель - *научиться самому*, то почему вы ни строчки js-кода вашего слайдера не добавили в вопрос?

Comment: пытаюсь на чистом css сделать

Comment: И как получается? По вашему коду никакой работы слайдера не наблюдается